# Asymptotic behavior of implied volatility at probability mass

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, asymptotics

For sake of simplicity, let us suppose that interest rate is zero, stock price is 1, and time to expiry is 1. I am interested in implied volatility that gives the following put price.
$$P(k, \sigma(k))= max(c(k-k_0), intrinsic(k))$$
Where $0 < c<1$ and $k$ is the strike, $intrinsic(k) = \max(k - 1, 0)$.
Since there is zero extrinsic value for puts with strike $k \leq k_0$, I know that
$$lim_{k\to k_0^+} \sigma(k) = 0$$
However, I would like to know the higher order term for $\sigma(k)$ around $k=k_0$.

Comment: Is $k$ in your notation strike or time to maturity?

Comment: I mean what kind of implied vol goes to zero as strike approaches ATM? So I am assuming $k$ is a weird notation for time to maturity, but then your question still does not make much sense to me.

Comment: I agree with Frido, you need to clarify this a bit